# Auto fit image in DIV is not working in bloger

Tags: html, css, image

I have written the following code to auto fit image in DIV. It is perfectly working in JSFIDDLE but not working in my blog http://roadroute.blogspot.in/2015/08/flipkart.html

Please find the code below

```css
.responsive-container1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 415px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-right: 10px; 
    margin-top:10px; 
    float: left; 
}

.dummy {
    padding-top: 100%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */
}

.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align:center; /* Align center inline elements */
    font: 0/0 a;
}

.img-container:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-container1">
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdTkowMFVRTDJTS00/01.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive-container1">
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdTkowMFVRTDJTS00/02.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive-container1">
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdTkowMFVRTDJTS00/03.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove following css:

```
.dummy {
    padding-top: 100%;
}

.img-container {
    bottom: 0;
    font: 0px/0 a;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
}
```

And `.post-body img` have have `padding: 8px;` will put/display your image outside div. Either remove that Or make image `max-width: 90%;`.

It will wok for you.

**Edit:**

Give: `text-align:center` to `.responsive-container1`.

```
.responsive-container1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 415px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
}
```

And max width and height `90%` and give `position` and `top` value And also  give `transform`.

```
.post-body img {
    background: #222222 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

It will do the trick.

Comment: I have changed by removing dummy and img-container. Now there is still two problems. One: Right side of the photo overlapping the div when photo is big. Two: The photo should be horizontally and vertically center.

Answer (score 1):

just add

> width:100%; height:100%;

in your image container class.

```css
.responsive-container1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 415px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-right: 10px; 
    margin-top:10px; 
    float: left; 
}

.dummy {
    padding-top: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */
}

.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align:center; /* Align center inline elements */
    font: 0/0 a;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

.img-container:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-container1">
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdTkowMFVRTDJTS00/01.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive-container1">
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdTkowMFVRTDJTS00/02.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive-container1">
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0BxPZgr7ebTBdTkowMFVRTDJTS00/03.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I provide u a code snippent run it. It works fine for me